# InputConnection.finishComposingText() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, crash-reports

I am getting this error log on crashlytics. I don't know what makes this crash.
It occurs on Android 4.x, 5.x, 6.x devices. (Samsung, Sony, LGE etc.)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocusNoStartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1809)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1761)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isActive(InputMethodManager.java:883)
   at android.widget.Editor$CursorAnchorInfoNotifier.updatePosition(Editor.java:4095)
   at android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw(Editor.java:2564)
   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1018)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2313)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7021)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: remove advance profiling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the input connection is not null in your onCreateInputConnection override method.

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    InputConnection inputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    if (inputConnection == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return new MyInputConnectionWrapper(inputConnection,
            true);
}
```

Where MyInputConnectionWrapper is your custom input connection wrapper which is extended from InputConnectionWrapper.

Comment: doesnt this till return null?

Comment: Can you suggest why is this problem occuring?

Comment: Worked for me, I had a custom class extending AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, added code in onCreateInputConnection() 
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 54):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440771/focus-on-edittext-result-in-crash/47451443#47451443), this can happen because of the  `Android Advanced Profiling` tool.

Disable it from the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog:

[image: disabling advanced profiling]

Comment: Any idea why `Advanced Profiling` is causing this issue?

Comment: I'm also curious. How is this connected?

Comment: disabling the option solves the issue but are they gonna provide the proper solution for this? ( Using Android Studio 3.1.3)

Comment: @AdeelJaved seems like it's fixed in AS 3.2 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77764953

Comment: @Aba thanks yes seems like they have fixed this in AS 3.2 Canary 18 version

Answer (score 10):

It also happened to me because of ***Advanced Profiling*** option is enabled.

To disable the advanced profiling, follow these steps:

1. Select ***Run*** > ***Edit Configurations***.
2. Select your app module in the left pane.
3. Click the ***Profiling*** tab, and then uncheck ***Enable advanced profiling***.
   [Learn more](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The above answer should be correct, but in my scenario, the reason for this error is:
Edittext is having focus, and this error occurs when `edittext.getText()` is used.
To avoid this error you must:
`edittext.gettext().toString();`

Note: This edittext must have focus to make this error.

Comment: Thanks you for posting an answer to this question. The code you posted is not properly [marked as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262), making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Please [edit] your post until it is easy to read and understand. Also read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the fragment or Activity have a non EditTextView named mTv; At some appropriate time,`mTv.requestFocuse()`; This works for me. Hope this helps you.