# focus on editText result in crash

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm experiencing a really unusual behavior:

From today (no style, Gradle or layout changes done), every-time I click on an `EditText` or `TextInputEditText` (just set focus on them), the app crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be
>   cast to android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.profilers.EventProfiler$InputConnectionHandler.run(EventProfiler.java:330)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I searched on the net and I didn't find anything similar and at the moment I'm really without any idea.

I tried it on two different **Huawei** devices with **Android 6.0** and both result in a crash.

If I run it on my phone (**Oneplus 3, Android 7**) I have no errors and the app works correctly.

What I tried:

- Changing the layout, one of those who were crashing
- Adding a simple `EditText` with no attributes set
- Removing all code and leaving the `Activity` "blank"
- Cleaning some gradle unused references
- Uninstalling app from phone
- Rebooting phone
- Invalidating

Not a single solution worked. What is happening to my application?

Thanks all

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice unfortunatly, this is the full stack trace

Comment: I have **Huawei Honor 7** with Android 5.0.2 and the same crash happened on `EditText` with Profiling enabled.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I had the same issue,my mobile is also Huawei with Android 6.0.You should set up android studio and close the android profiler in Settings.I wish that can help you .

[image]

Comment: I'm so glad I could help you, and I spent a couple of hours checking out the problem.Release apk runs without any problems on the phone.

Comment: Funny that advanced profiling used for better tracking of memory leaks causes massive memory leaks and crashes itself. I had the same problem working on pre Oreo devices. I observed memory spikes and/or crashes, thank you for the post.

Comment: Disable it, yes. It make my app crash!

Answer (score 7):

Not only open profiler can cause `ClassCastException` on same Huawei devices, but also it may cause

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference

wish help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the full stack trace was only two lines so that I could not find more useful information.

So, I uninstalled my application from mobile, rebooted it, I also cleaned the project on Android Studio, and tried again, when I opened the activity that crashed before, it ran normally as usual.
my mobile is also  Huawei with Android 6.0 , I wish that can help you .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatly I already tried this yesterday, I tried it again today but without any success