# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be cast to android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection

Tags: android, gradle

> In thread: Thread[Thread-484,5,main]
>   UncaughtException detected: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be cast to
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.profilers.EventProfiler$InputConnectionHandler.run(EventProfiler.java:330)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) In thread:
>   Thread[Thread-484,5,main]
>                                                                              UncaughtException detected: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.ref.SoftReference cannot be cast to
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.profilers.EventProfiler$InputConnectionHandler.run(EventProfiler.java:330)at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

here is  my AS setting

```
 <component name="GradleSettings">
<option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
  <GradleProjectSettings>
    <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
    <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
    <!--<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-4.1" />-->
    <option name="modules">
      <set>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" />
      </set>
    </option>
```

here is setting

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`enter code here`
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
```

Comment: in my phone can't run normally ,will be case crash ;but in another phone  run perfect? i can see the splashAcivity appear but suddenly crash? how can i fix it?

Comment: i found the solution here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440771/focus-on-edittext-result-in-crash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [focus on editText result in crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440771/focus-on-edittext-result-in-crash)