# Clicking inside SearchView restarts application

Tags: android, searchview

So, this is interesting case. I've a `SearchView` in my `Toolbar`. The moment I click inside `SearchView` application automatically re-starts. This happens when I use specific model: Huawei P9 Lite. Any other device I tried on emulator - works as expected. I tried to Log a message in `onConfigurationChange()`, but nothing was displayed so the reason behind this is unknown.

My Activity manifest looks like:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:label=""
    android:parentActivityName=".Activity" />
```

What could cause this?

Comment: *`Clicking inside SearchView restarts application`*  means your application is carsh you need to share **`crash log`** with question

Comment: @NileshRathod There is no crash log. Application just restarts.

Comment: `android:name=".Activity" android:parentActivityName=".Activity"` what does it mean ?

Comment: **Also i dont know u can assign a base class name directly to a subclass** `Activity` and `AppCompatActivity` are base classes !!

Comment: @PeteWonder its not that there's no crash log. The crash log is cleared when the application restarts. Are you using a device with ZUI by any chance?

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya No, I'm not.

Comment: adb shell logcat -s YOUR_TAG, it won't be cleared and you will be able to see the logs of  your app if there are crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

After few days, the answer was found on SO:
[focus on editText result in crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440771/focus-on-edittext-result-in-crash)

You have to disable "Advanced profiling"