# NullPointerException calling InputConnection.finishComposingText()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Running my app I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:362)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

The problem is that this is not called directly from my app code. One or two seconds after my activity started I get the exception.

What could be causing it?

<sub>[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498605/inputconnection-finishcomposingtext-nullpointerexception) does not solve my question since I do not use the `InputConnection` anywhere in my code.</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498605/inputconnection-finishcomposingtext-nullpointerexception Any help you could get from this?

Comment: I don't use `InputConnection` anywhere in my code.

Comment: It's too early to mark this as duplicate!

Comment: Show your launching activity code.

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir: Not possible since it is a really big one.

Comment: You need to find out what triggers this exception. Since `InputConnection` class is related to input, I believe some UI component might be the culprit!

Comment: Are u using some Handler ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440771/focus-on-edittext-result-in-crash?rq=1) might help?

Comment: @Abhi: Already tried it. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir: I don't.

Comment: there is nothing we can do to reproduce the crash. So someone in similar situation can only answer this.

Comment: Juergen, you've been around here long enough to know that without something to go with, the question isn't answerable.